# Creating data for Google pie chart

Tags: php, javascript, google-api

I guess this maybe more of a maths question but I'll try anyway! I'm using a Google pie chart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) to display my data.

How can I create a full pie chart, at the moment it's just creating tiny slices that don't fill the whole pie!

The data is gathered from Wordpress - it's just counting how many companies are either academic, business or clinical. These are variables like the following:

```
<p>Academic<?php echo $academic;?></p>
<p>Business<?php echo $business;?></p>
<p>Clinical<?php echo $clinical;?></p>
```

For my test data that has output the numbers 1, 2 and 1. By just putting the variables into the code it creates tiny slices, how can I fill the pie?

**The pie in the google example adds up to 24 so what would be the equation? P.s I'm rubbish at maths!**

---

```
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Academic', '<?php echo $academic; ?>'],
          ['Business', '<?php echo $business; ?>'],
          ['Clinical', '<?php echo $clinical; ?>']
        ]);

        var options = {
          backgroundColor: 'none',
          chartArea: {width:"221",height:"221"},
          width:'221',
          height:'221',
          legend: {position: 'none'},
          tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
          enableInteractivity: false,
          slices: {0: {color: '#a95892'}, 1:{color: '#d7663a'}, 2:{color: '#316086'}}
        };

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
      draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (at least it does for me in the Code Playground):

```
function drawVisualization() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Type', 'Amount'],
    ['Academic', <?php echo $academic;?>],
    ['Business', <?php echo $business;?>],
    ['Clinical', <?php echo $clinical;?>]]);
new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).draw(data, {title:"how many?"});
}
```

http://h3n.info/pie.png

Comment: All that's done from the google example is change "hours per day" to "Amount"... it still will only plot small segments, not fill the whole pie.

Comment: but it does in the Code Playground (https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart)

Comment: Maybe you have additional code that changes the default behaviour of the pie chart, paste your full code please. This is how it looks like in my browser: http://h3n.info/pie.png

Comment: Just pasted my code. Hmm, it works in the playground but not on my site - it just shows the small segments.

Comment: You wrote '<?php echo $academic;?>' which generates '2' which is a string and not the expected integer value. try removing the apostrophes (').